# Excel VBA Range object is set, but inner objects are missing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a confusing problem with my VBA Range object. Here is the relevant code in first

```
Option Explicit
Dim lastSelection As Range    ' <= Always remember last Selection

Private Function UpdateNeeded() As Boolean
    UpdateNeeded = False

    If IsEmpty(lastSelection) Then
        Debug.Print "UpdateReason: lastSelection=<Empty>"
        UpdateNeeded = True

    ElseIf lastSelection Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "UpdateReason: lastSelection=<Nothing>"
        UpdateNeeded = True

    ' Next line causes an "Object-Missing" exception
    ElseIf Selection.Count <> lastSelection.Count Then 
        Debug.Print "UpdateReason: Selection.Count <> lastSelection.Count"
        UpdateNeeded = True

    ' ElseIf  (A lot of other if statements always to be handled the same way ...)
    End If

End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If UpdateNeeded Then
        Set lastSelection = Selection
        'UpdateAllCharts ' Update all my containing charts into worksheet.
    End If

End Sub
```

This is working fine until I start to delete cells when they are holded in lastSelection. Then it causes an "Object-Missing" exception. Debugging the objects will look like this:

```
| Expression      | Value             | Type        | Context
+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+------------------------
|   lastSelection |                   | Range/Range | Sheet1.Worksheet_Change
|   |- ...        | "Object Required" |  ...        | Sheet1.Worksheet_Change
|   |- Cells      | "Object Required" | Range       | Sheet1.Worksheet_Change
|   |- Count      | "Object Required" | Long        | Sheet1.Worksheet_Change
|   |- ...        | "Object Required" |  ...        | Sheet1.Worksheet_Change
```

I know what is happening, but I don't know how to handle this. IsEmpty, is Nothing, IsMissing won't change anything. The only way seems to set OnError, but in some cases an error can be caused by an opposite way and so I must not automatically update my charts.

I've googled a lot, but I'm not able to find any solution for this. Can someone help me?

And by the way, how can I realize tables here? HTML seems not to be working.

Thx in Advance

Comment: stupid question: why don't you store the "selection" in a Range variable and then, after deleting the cell, select the range which your variable has in?

Comment: Hi Noldor130884. This is excactly what I'm doing. (Or did you mean something else?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what revision issue you're trying to capture with the `Selection.Count <> lastSelection.Count` statement, so my code probably needs some changes to work in your situation, but I think if you work directly with the predefined `Target` variable instead of defining a Module scoped `Range` variable, it will let you solve the `Object-Missing` exception.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking. This code does not get an `Object-missing` exception when a cell or row is deleted:

```
Option Explicit
Dim lastSelection As Long '~> Always remember the count of last Target

Private Function UpdateNeeded(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean '~>Pass target and
                                                                   'use that range
    UpdateNeeded = False
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then '~> Passed argument instead of module variable
        Debug.Print "UpdateReason: lastSelection=<Empty>"
        UpdateNeeded = True
    ElseIf Target Is Nothing Then '~> Passed argument instead of module variable
        Debug.Print "UpdateReason: lastSelection=<Nothing>"
        UpdateNeeded = True
    '~>"Object-Missing" exception no longer occurs on deletion, but does this still
       'do what you want?
    ElseIf Target.Count <> lastSelection Then
        Debug.Print "UpdateReason: Selection.Count <> lastSelection.Count"
        UpdateNeeded = True
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If UpdateNeeded(Target) Then
        lastSelection = Target.Count '~> tracking against Target.Count could eliminate
                                         'the reference issue.
        'UpdateAllCharts
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't only the count property to be parsed. I'll split them all up into single variables and give it a try.